# Angular tsd based application + Spring Boot in JAR

Tags: angularjs, maven, spring-boot, jar, tsd

I have faced a problem connected with project config. I am working on an application which consist of server-side (Spring Boot App) and client-side(Angular-Gulp). I would like to configure my project so that when I build a jar file it would include both client and server side. What should I start with? I am using maven. Is it even possible? (if you need some of my code to answer this question just let me know).

Thanks in advance for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to checkout the article in this location. I too found it difficult when it was not in the standard documentation for the spring boot folder structure.

https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/19/serving-static-web-content-with-spring-boot

If you place the final artifacts form your gulp build to be in one of the folders that spring boot recognizes as web folder will do the trick.

I tried to do the same with Angular2 and Spring Boot and it did work. Please see the my project https://github.com/reflexdemon/shop and let me know your feedback.